# textViewDidBeginEditing not working in IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

i'm new in Objective C . What i'm going to do is simple just to animate keyboard up when textfield is focused and shrink when it's not. I already followed some other tutorial on how to set up this step by step but it not working.The event textViewDidBeginEditing is never get called when textfeld is focus.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *cCodeTextField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *jidTextField;

- (IBAction)nextBtnTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

I'm also set the delegate to the textfield but it's not working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addTextFieldBorder:_jidTextField];
    [self addTextFieldBorder:_cCodeTextField];

    _jidTextField.delegate = self;
}

-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSLog(@"Enter");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your ViewController class is implementing methods from the wrong delegate. It is implementing **UITextViewDelegate** methods when it should be implementing **UITextFieldDelegate** methods.

Note that 'jidTextField' is of type **UITextField**.

Your delegate method is called 'textViewDidBeginEditing' which is a **UITextViewDelegate** method and takes a **UITextView** as a parameter.

The issue here is that your class is implementing delegate functions for **UITextViewDelegate** and not **UITextFieldDelegate**.

The correct method definition is:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Here is a link to the documentation for the correct delegate:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh. I just notice that right now.. Thanks, you save my day :) .

Comment: But there is no textFieldShouldBeginEditing in the list, maybe it was deprecated. I guess should use this one -> textFieldDidBeginEditing.